# Showing $\sup_{\Vert w \Vert_\infty} |v^\ast w| = \Vert v \Vert_1$ for $v \neq 0$

Tags: real-analysis, numerical-linear-algebra

### Problem

> Show, for $v \neq 0 \in \mathbb{C}^n$
>   $$
> \sup_{\Vert w \Vert_\infty=1} |v^\ast w| = \Vert v \Vert_1
> $$
>
> And find the similar equality for $\sup_{\Vert w \Vert_1=1} |v^\ast w|$

---

### Try

Since $|v^\ast w| = \cos\theta \Vert v \Vert_2 \Vert w \Vert_2$, geometrically

$$
\sup_{\Vert w \Vert_2=1} |v^\ast w| = \Vert v \Vert_2
$$

is direct, since this means the Euclidean distance from origin of the orthogonally projected vector on $w$.

However, $\Vert w \Vert_\infty$ and $\Vert w \Vert_1$ form kind of "boxes", so I'm stuck at how I should proceed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First show that $|v^*w|\leq\|v\|_1\|w\|_\infty$. This is a special case of the [Holder's inequality](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/H%C3%B6lder%27s_inequality), which is particularly easy:
$$
\begin{split}
|v^*w|&=\left|\sum_{i=1}^n \bar{v}_i w_i\right|
\leq\sum_{i=1}^n |v_i||w_i|
\leq\left(\sum_{i=1}^n |v_i|\right)\left(\max_{1\leq i\leq n}|w_i|\right)
=\|v\|_1\|w\|_\infty.
\end{split}
$$

The inequality is attained if we can find a $w$ such that $\bar{v}_i w_i=|v_i|$ and $\|w\|_\infty=1$. This is easily done. If $v_i=|v_i|e^{\iota \theta_i}$ (where $\iota$ is the imaginary unit), then choosing $w_i=e^{\iota\theta_i}$ gives $\bar{v}_iw_i=|v_i|e^{-\iota\theta_i}e^{\iota\theta_i}=|v_i|$ and $|w_i|=1$ so $\|w\|_\infty=1$. Hence $|v^*w|=\|v\|_1\|w\|_\infty$.